# Why does the Blessing of talos have this effect?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I got a disease from killing some skeevers and I went to Whiterun to the Talos shrine. I activated which cured myself. I looked in active effects just to see a fortify shouting effect like this:

[image: blessingoftalos]

The effect says, "Time between shouts is reduced 0%". Is this a glitch? Is it preventing me from fortifying shouts? Only the Amulet of Talos has 20% Fortify Shouting.

Comment: Why redoing that upvote?

Answer (score 8):

Per the UESPWiki's [entry on blessings](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blessing_of_Talos#note_DisplayError):

> The details of the Blessing of Talos are bugged when viewed in-game.
>   The magnitude is displayed as "0%" (truncated from 0.2). Nevertheless,
>   the blessing does still have an effect.

The blessing reduces time between shouts by 20%. The value is stored as a decimal (0.2) but rather than converting it to a percent for display purposes, it just reads the decimal value and truncates everything after the decimal place, resulting in the game showing 0%.

This display error is fixed in the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes5Mod:Unofficial_Skyrim_Patch).